# How do I setup and learn the use of Selendroid for Android testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, mobile, android, selendroid

I am a manual tester with knowledge in selenium webdriver but as I see that [selendriod](http://selendroid.io/) came in for mobile app testing.

### My question is

What would be the best place from where anyone can learn selendroid from scratch ? I went to the official site but was not able to understand properly

Any book, link, website, blog would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set the Selendriod up last week with this guide on the official site [selendroid.io/setup.html](http://selendroid.io/setup.html). It's a step by step since System Requirements to the first test case. I think it's a good kickstart, pretty straight forward.

You could post for a specific question, if you are struggling in any step.

Hope it helps,

Comment: For some of the steps previous Android application development knowledge would be handy. That will bring some commands/steps into context. Maybe the O.P. can look into an initial test setup with the original developer of the App under test.